# Chrome Extension: Even with jQuery properly referenced in manifest $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

Having already read the bevy of posts on this error, I wrote my manifest like so:

```
{
    "name": "Chrome extension",
    "description": "Content Sanitzer",
    "version": "2.0",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "TBD"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "content.js"]
    }],

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Despite having the jQuery file mentioned twice in the manifest, before both the background and content scripts, and having everything in one location (i.e., the files for the extensions that I wrote, in addition to the minified jQuery file appropriately referenced above), an error appears at the first sign of a `$` in my code (Uncaught Reference Error $ Undefined appears on the line that reads `$('li#nav-chat').replaceWith(" ");`). The jQuery works perfectly fine on its own in the console, but not in a Chrome Extension context.

Does anyone else have any thoughts as to what else I can do to fix this issue? There is no popup, and thus no html, so there are no script tags to add.

EDIT: Sample code below from content.js -- it's just a jQuery file.

```
var profanity = /words/gi;

// obtain web page url for eventual identification
var url = window.location.href;

console.log(url);

if (url === "http://www.example.net/") {
    // disable chat link -- the error appears here and will not execute the following line or anything below
   $('li#nav-chat').replaceWith(" ");
   // sanitize headlines embedded in a tags; disable ones containing profanity
   $('a').each(function() {
    var headlineText = $(this).text();
    if (headlineText.match(profanity)) {
        headlineText = headlineText.replace(profanity, "***");
```

EDIT: Entire background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: 'content.js'
  });
});
```

Comment: @wOxxOm - Question edited for clarity, code added, yes, I reloaded the extension multiple times.

Comment: If the posted code is in `content.js`, it should work. The error you see may be caused by inserting the code in a `script` element e.g. by doing it explicitly (or implicitly via `require()` and such), because it's no longer a content script, but just a page script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Not sure that I follow. I have no html anywhere (just posted my background.js file), so no `<script>` tags and have not used `.require()` anywhere. Could it be happening implicitly by another means? Or could there by another source of the error? Appreciate the help, btw.

Comment: Background page is a separate hidden page. If you want to process contents of web pages in browser tabs you need to use content scripts, see also [the architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Right. That's what I thought was going on. My background page called my content script which used my jQuery to process the page. The error appears because the jQuery does not seem to load before the jQuery code in the content script, content.js, is read, which is odd given how everything is presented in the manifest and all requisite files are organised in the extension.

Comment: By default the content scripts in manifest are injected after DOMContentLoaded. You may want to specify `"run_at": "document_start"`, see the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Genius! That did it. The docs are a bit overwhelming to the uninitiated. Consider moving response to formal a answer rather than a comment, so that I can give you proper credit by upvoting and accepting!